# Python Selenium Firefox driver - Disable Images

Tags: python, image, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, loadimage

Before I have used the code below, but it doesn't work anymore with firefox update.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
```

I also tried this one below, it seems good but is there a way to disable images without add-on or 3rd party tools?

```
from selenium import webdriver
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.add_extension(folder_xpi_file_saved_in + "\\quickjava-2.0.6-fx.xpi")
firefox_profile.set_preference("thatoneguydotnet.QuickJava.startupStatus.Images", 2)  ## Turns images off
```

Comment: Setting `permissions.default.image` works for me on Firefox 66.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your selenium after the Firefox update?

eg :

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade selenium
```

Comment: It is up to date. Actually this is the problem. Because the first code worked before, after firefox and selenium updates, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Ah, okay. I mentioned this because the statement (which was working fine earlier) :  

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  

started giving me this error :  
WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details  

which got resolved after the selenium update.